# Showing DateTime without time in a DataGridView

Tags: .net, vb.net, date, datetime, ms-access

I'm making a program to save and show match statistics in Visual Basic .NET.
Now I just have a problem with showing the date in my program.
Reading from the database (MS Access) goes, and I show everything in a `DataGridView`.

For showing the date, I use the line `dgvWedstrijden.Rows.Item(n).Cells(1).Value = dataReader(1).Date`.
But when I do this, the date shows as `9/10/2014 00:00:00`.
If I don't type the `.Date`, then the hour is not `00:00:00`, but `14:15:26`.

Instead of the line I showed before, I also used:

```
Dim datum As DateTime = FormatDateTime(dataReader(1), 1)
dgvWedstrijden.Rows.Item(n).Cells(1).Value = datum.Date
```

but this gives the same result.

Can someone help me how to show the date without the time (so without the `00:00:00`)? I can't use `ToString`, because then it's not possible to order the column by date.

Thank you

```
Public Sub updateWedstrijden()
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim dbProvider As String
    Dim dbSource As String
    Dim dataReader As OleDbDataReader
    Dim addnewcommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand

    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    dbSource = "Data Source = D:\De Koarters\Kalender\Minivoetbal\Minivoetbal\DatabaseMinivoetbal.accdb"
    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

    dgvWedstrijden.Rows.Clear()

    addnewcommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT SeizoenTornooi,Datum,Startuur,Tegenstander,DoelpuntenTegen,DoelpuntenVoor FROM Wedstrijden", con)
    con.Open()

    dataReader = addnewcommand.ExecuteReader
    While dataReader.Read()
        Dim n As Integer = dgvWedstrijden.Rows.Add()
        dgvWedstrijden.Rows.Item(n).Cells(0).Value = dataReader(0)
        dgvWedstrijden.Rows.Item(n).Cells(1).Value = dataReader(1).Date
        dgvWedstrijden.Rows.Item(n).Cells(2).Value = dataReader(2).ToString.Substring(0, 2) & "u" & dataReader(2).ToString.Substring(2, 2)
        dgvWedstrijden.Rows.Item(n).Cells(3).Value = dataReader(3)
        dgvWedstrijden.Rows.Item(n).Cells(4).Value = dataReader(4) & "-" & dataReader(5)
    End While

    dataReader.Close()
    con.Close()

    dgvWedstrijden.Sort(dgvWedstrijden.Columns(0), ListSortDirection.Ascending)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a problem of [formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f9x2790s(v=vs.100).aspx), store in the cell the date *as is* so you won't loose time part in ordering and change column formatting to show only date part:

```
dgvWedstrijden.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "d"

While dataReader.Read()
    dgvWedstrijden.Rows.Item(n).Cells(1).Value = dataReader(1)
End While
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than manipulate the string on a cell-by-cell basis there, you could format the column on the dgv.  Should let you retain type for potentially simpler sorting later on.

```
dgView.Columns["<Column Name Here>"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MMM/yyyy"
```